# Flip card (turnover) animation from two still images

Tags: kdenlive

I want to create an animation from two still images. One still is the front of a card, the other is the back, and I want the animation to turn over the card. [Here](is an example in Adobe After Effects]. I looked at the Wipe transitions that are built-in, as well as the add-ons provided by the community, and they all seem 2D transitions with an animated opacity mask between the two images, whereas this one would be closer to 3D with perspective and distortion.

Is it possible in Kdenlive to produce a "flip card" turnover animation?